# How can conduct a change in R square test in a multiple regression analysis?

Tags: r, r-squared

I am working on a multiple regression analysis and want to compare two models. I was asked to conduct a change in R square test and interpret. How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to take a look at adjusted R2.

Comment: http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/multiple-regession-analysis-use-adjusted-r-squared-and-predicted-r-squared-to-include-the-correct-number-of-variables

Comment: Whenever you add or remove a variable, the R-square changes. I think it would be helpful if you: (1) try and get a bit more detail about the envisaged "change in R square test", as my guess is that this is just vague language rather than a well-known test; (2) indicated whether your models are nested or not (i.e,. is one model the same as the other, but with fewer variables), as this has a big impact on the testing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a relatively simple formula you can find here: http://onlinestatbook.com/2/regression/multiple_regression.html

The formula on this page is in terms of sums of squares. If you divide the sums of squares by the sum of squares total you get the formula in terms of R^2"s.